# Confirmation box on cancel button and cross (rigth hand corner)

Tags: jquery, custom-form

Whenever I leave a page as in exit the page like click the cross button or cancel button it should ask for confirmation -Do i want to navigate from the page(Yes/No)
If No, it should remain on the same page.
This is easy to implement on MOSS 2007 using onbeforeunload event using Jquery.
But 2010 all pages namely Newform, Editform and DisplayForm are Modal Dialog and I am not able to use this event efficiently.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could go into the settings of the list or library and set them to open in the browser instead. Then you should be able to do this.

Comment: but will tat give me a confirmation ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this behavior on every single form in your Site Collection, you can certainly do it with jQuery added to the master page. It's just a matter of getting the selectors right. You'll need to handle the buttons on forms which are displayed in dialogs as well as those which are not.

However, might I suggest that you will drive your users absolutely batty with this "enhancement"?